# How I can remove space between two tags

Tags: css

I'm new in HTML and CSS I tried to remove this space in image below but It's not working never

[Preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmFlD.png)

*HTML*

```
<body>
<header>
    <hr>
    <h1>For<span>Test</span></h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>d</li>
            <li>e</li>
            <li>f</li>
            <li>g</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

*CSS*

```
body {
    margin: auto;
}

/* Start header */

header nav {
    background-color: #171f21;
    margin: 0px 0px;
}

header hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #ff8900;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    display: block;
}

header h1 {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #ff8900;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: inline;
}

header span {
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* End header */
```

I searched before send post here I found good results but not working with me..............................................

Comment: The <ul> has margin. Add this to your css `ul { margin: 0 }`

Comment: @kmgt thanks a lot It's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can work for you. There is margin with UL. so remove it to remove space.

```css
body {
    margin: auto;
}

/* Start header */

header nav {
    background-color: #171f21;
    margin: 0px 0px;
}ul{margin:0;}

header hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #ff8900;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    display: block;
}

header h1 {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #ff8900;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: inline;
}

header span {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
    <hr>
    <h1>For<span>Test</span></h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>d</li>
            <li>e</li>
            <li>f</li>
            <li>g</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
```

Comment: there is no any different

Comment: i have updated, check again